# Working on a Rails Application with Designers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, collaboration

I'm currently programming a Rails application locally using RVM.

Now I want a designer to join me, building some html code, css and js for this application.
I don't want him to learn all stuff with bundler, updating databases and so on, so simply sharing a git-repo won't do the trick.

Is there a simple solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hardest part is really the development environment for such there is vagrant. 
You setup everything in vagrant, then he downloads it, and does.

```
rails s
```

he is done:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/292-virtual-machines-with-vagrant

Comment: i tried vagrant now and i'm not so super happy with it. you often have to share the VM, especially in early development stages which is not very effective if your working remotely with your partners. 600mb up and downloading and installing each time when you start/leave work is too much.

Comment: hm for remote workers you might just want to freeze up the VM, so they only have to download it once...I don't see why they have to do it each time they start working ?

Comment: not everytime. but often you add things to applications that require external software like imagemagick and stuff like that. for this, they have to re-dowload it. and personally for me, working as a developer always with this vnc machine slows down my dev-speed. probably good for designers but bad for me =/

Answer (score 1):

I always make bash scripts to install and update my Rails projects.

So I might have this `./script/install` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e # stop the script as soon as an error occurs

echo "--- Making sure bundler is installed"
gem which bundler &> /dev/null || gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc

echo "--- Installing gems"
bundle check || bundle install

echo "--- Setting up the database"
bundle exec rake db:setup db:test:prepare

echo "--- Running tests to see if everying installed correctly"
bundle exec rspec spec
bundle exec cucumber features --profile all

echo "--- Everything installed correctly!"
echo "--- Run `rails server` to start the server!"
```

Comment: this is a world of pain. you still need ruby. You'll need a compileryo get ruby. Your rake database will need migrations constantly. If you use something other that sqlite(mongodb, postgres) you will need to install it etc etc etc. Its just better for you to maintain a virtual environment, and they just consume it.